# reading a csv file from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am using the following code to read a CSV file from my current working directory:

```py
wine = pd.read_csv('..wine.csv')
```

I'm not sure why I receive this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'../python projects/wine.csv' does not exist: b'../python projects/wine.csv'
```

I also tried:

```py
wine = pd.read_csv('../wine.csv')
```

and

```py
wine = pd.read_csv("../wine.csv")
```

Then I tried and it worked:

```py
wine = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Me/wine.csv")
```

Why don't the other codes work?  I always thought putting two dots  for example ('../wine.csv') takes the csv file from the current working directory

thanks everyone in advance

Comment: The '../' is searching the **parent** directory, whereas a single dot './' searches the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python file and CSV file are in the same directory then you just have to write

`wine= pd.read_csv('wine.csv')`

By using `../` you are going outside your working directory.

Comment: thanks so much !  WHere does the code "../ " take you? Does it take you to the next level outsdie your current directory?  thnx

Comment: Suppose you have the following directory structure  A->B->C->D and you are in the 'C' directory and 'cd ../' will take you to the 'B' directory (ie: the parent directory)

Answer (score 0):

First of all search for current working directory:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
Out[2]:
'/any_folder_name'
In [3]:
```

Then, move your csv file to that folder then run:

```
data = pd.read_csv('wine.csv')
```

Comment: Awesome thank you sooo much ! What is the significance of the two dots in the code:    wine = pd.read_csv("../wine.csv")  ?  I seem to see the two dot reference in some books saying it will get me to the current directory. Also it seems that a single quote works as well as the double qoutes. Is this true?  thanks

Comment: is your csv file in parent directory??

Answer (score -1):

Python fails to recognize paths that have spaces in them even if it is not explicitely mentioned.

"../python projects/wine.csv" has a space between "python" and "proyects" even if it is hidden on the shortcut of "../wine.csv"

That is why it worked when you moved the file to a path without spaces like "C:/Users/Me/wine.csv".

Next time use underline or camelcase when you name your folders to avoid messing up the path.

Comment: The space is not the reason the file could not be found.  The user was searching the parent directory, rather than the current directory.